# How to crop the video?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I want to crop the video at particular portion.Given height,width,x and y ,I want crop the particular region on the video.Does anyone have any idea.

I have done lot of research but didn't find anything fruitful.I tried cropping using GPUImage Cropfilter but it is taking too much time.

I want to perform this operation as quick as possible,Please suggest me the technique or example how to do it.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387756/ipad-crop-the-video-and-play-cropped-portion-only

Comment: I tried that, But it didn't crop the video in final output.

Comment: It just show user the cropped portion,but when video is exported, it is as it was... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`AVMutableComposition`**  and **`AVAssetExportSession`** Which are available in **`AVFoundation Framework`**

For more detail visit apple's reference library [AVMutableComposition Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html)     and 
   [AVAssetExportSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetExportSession)

```
AVAsset* asset = // Create your asset with source video url

AVMutableComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [videoComposition              addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo     preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComposition = [[AVMutableVideoComposition    videoComposition]retain];
videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320, 240);
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction =    [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60, 30) );

 AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* transformer =    [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction    videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:clipVideoTrack];
CGAffineTransform finalTransform = // setup a transform that grows the video, effectively causing a crop
[transformer setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:transformer];
videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

CGSize videoSize = myVideoComposition.renderSize;

CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];

CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];

NSLog(@"%f %f",_playerLayer.frame.origin.x,_playerLayer.frame.size.width);

parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0  , cropsize.x , cropsize.y );

[videoLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(videoLayer.position.x, videoSize.height)];

[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];


videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:saveComposition    presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality] ;
exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition;
exporter.outputURL=url3;
exporter.outputFileType=AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

 [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){}];
```

Comment: I already used this code,the function CGAffineTransformMake() of CGAffineTransform class only flip or rotate video frames horizontally or vertically but doesn't crop it !!! See this are things that you can do with CGAffinetransformMake (check this link) 

http://tiddlyspace.com/bags/iphonesnipplets_public/tiddlers/CGAffineTransformMake/revisions/115363

Comment: please check above I have edited answer now we are cropping parent layer on which we have to add video layer as child so after export we will get cropped video

Comment: What is cropsize.x and cropsize.y are they are the cordinates from where we have start croping ???

Comment: The above code doesn't work !! plus you are creating two objects with same name videoComposition...